# Fragment is still visible after remove method

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have a problem with fragments in my program - it is still visible after **getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(selectSectionFragment).commit()** method. But when I change screen mode (for example - to landscape) in emulator - the fragment is gone (what I am need).

public class AddCardActivity extends Activity {

```
private EditText sectionChoiceField;
private android.app.FragmentTransaction fTrans;
private SelectSectionFragment selectSectionFragment;

private String selectedSectionName;
private int selectedSectionId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_card);

    TextView topTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addCardTextView);       
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mainmenu_button_font.ttf");
    topTitle.setTypeface(font);

    sectionChoiceField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sectionChoice);
    selectSectionFragment = new SelectSectionFragment();

    sectionChoiceField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
            fTrans.add(R.id.add_card_container, selectSectionFragment);
            fTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
            fTrans.show(selectSectionFragment);
            fTrans.commit();
        }
    });
}

public void setSectionToField(String name, int id) {
    sectionChoiceField.setText(name);
    selectedSectionName = name;
    selectedSectionId = id; 
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(selectSectionFragment).commit();
}
```

}

As you see in code block - first of all is executed successfully.

```
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
            fTrans.add(R.id.add_card_container, selectSectionFragment);
            fTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
            fTrans.show(selectSectionFragment);
            fTrans.commit();
```

But the execution of setSectionToField method - doesn't destroy fragment from activity - it's still visible, and I can manipulate with it. BUT getBackStackEntryCount() return 0 - so the fragment is Untouched, but still visible. Don't know how to "kill" this problem (((

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify wich SelectSectionFragment you want to remove, since you added it to R.id.add_card_container, try this:

```
SelectSectionFragment frag = (SelectSectionFragment)getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.add_card_container);
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.remove(frag); fTrans.commit();
```